# Using external commands in a perl console

Tags: perl

I have written a script using perl comnsole Term::ReadLine::Gnu.
How can I run while I'm in the console external commands in the background?
I've managed to support various external commands such as ls -l etc. but I also wish to support running commands in the background such as emacs &, but I can't seem to be able to get a process to run in the background.
Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute something in the background, you can use `system`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

system q(emacs &);
print "hello";
```

This will open emacs in the background and print "hello" straight away. If you removed the `&` in the command it would wait for emacs to close before printing "hello".

As pointed out by @Brad in the comments, note that this will only work on systems where the shell understands the `&`. If you were running on Windows for example, you would have to change the `system` line to something like this:

```
system q(start /b program.exe);
```

See the [system documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) for more details.

Comment: That will only work systems where the shell understands the trailing `&`, so you would have to come up with something else on those systems. ( Windows for example )

Comment: I wasn't even thinking about `start`, I was thinking of perhaps using Win32::API or similar. `start` is probably better in this circumstance.

Comment: @Brad I have absolutely no experience of running Perl on Windows so if there's a better way, by all means feel free to suggest one :) I assumed that the OP was running on a UNIX-like system as they mention `Term::ReadLine::Gnu` in the question.

Comment: Thanks, what I did was to differentiate between commands entered with & at the end, and then I used the system function, and regular commands, and then I used two ticks `` so that I could capture the output and print it.